# Derivative of scalar multiple of matrix by scalar

Tags: matrices, derivatives

Let X be a n x m matrix and let $\gamma$ be a scalar. What is the derivative of $\gamma X$ with respect to $\gamma$ and X is not a function of $\gamma$? ie

$$
\frac{\partial \gamma X}{\partial \gamma} = ?
$$

I think it might be X but I always thought that the dimensions stay the same, meaning, the derivative should also be a scalar since $\gamma$ is scalar. Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you referring to the map $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{n \times m} \, ; \, \gamma  \mapsto \gamma X$? If so this map is linear and continuous, so $Df (\gamma)= f$ for every $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$. Or are you referring to the scalar multiplication map $g: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^{n \times m} \to \mathbb{R}^{n \times m} \, ; \, (t,A) \mapsto tA$.

Comment: I am trying to take the derivative with respect to $\gamma$ of this function $h(\gamma)=(Y - \gamma X)^T(Y - \gamma X)$ where $Y$ is an n x m matrix. I am interested in the value of $\gamma$ that minimizes $h$. So in your notation, it's the map $g$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$W=\gamma X-Y$$ Write a function in terms of the norm of this new variable, and find its derivative 
$$\eqalign{
 f &= \|W\|_F^2 = W:W \cr\cr
df &= 2W:dW = 2W:X\,d\gamma \cr\cr
\frac{df}{d\gamma} &= 2W:X = 2(\gamma X-Y):X \cr\cr
}$$
Set the derivative to zero and solve for $\gamma$
$$\eqalign{
 \gamma X:X &= Y:X \,\,\implies\,\, \gamma &= \frac{Y:X}{X:X} \cr\cr
}$$
The colon represents the Frobenius product, which is a convenient infix notation for the trace, i.e. $$\eqalign{A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)\cr\cr}$$

If you actually wanted to minimize the function
$$h=\|W^TW\|_F^2$$ 
the process would be similar -- but this function seems unnatural.
$$\eqalign{
 \frac{dh}{d\gamma} &= 4WW^TW:X = 0 \cr
0 &= (\gamma X-Y)(\gamma X-Y)^T(\gamma X-Y):X \cr
}$$
This is a cubic polynomial in $\gamma$ whose coefficients are complicated scalar products of the $(X,Y)$ matrices. It seems really unlikely that this is what you were after.

Comment: Greg's answer also minimizes the trace of $(W^TW)$, since $${\rm tr}(W^TW)=W:W=f$$

Comment: This was really helpful, thank you

Comment: Hi @greg, what if we need to perform a gradient descent update instead, i.e.,: $\gamma_i = \gamma_{i-1} - \alpha \frac{d f}{d \gamma}$. The derivative here has a matrix form?

Comment: Since $f$ and $\gamma$ are scalars, the derivative is also a scalar, so I'm not sure what you mean by the derivative having  _"a matrix form"_

Answer (score 0):

If $X,Y$ are fixed members in the banach space $\mathbf{E} := \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ and $$h : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbf{E} \,\,\, ; \,\,\, t \mapsto (Y - tX)^T(Y - tX)$$
then for a fixed real number $t$ the total derivative $Dh(t) : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbf{E}$ is the continuous linear transformation that sends
$$ s \mapsto s(-Y^TX - X^TY + 2tX^TX).$$
In otherwords $Dh(t) = -Y^TX - X^TY + 2tX^TX$.